# Ubuntu 14.04 GEFORCE GTX 970

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, cuda, nvidia-geforce

I am using NVIDIA GTX 970 graphics card on Ubuntu Desktop 14.04LTS (64-bit). I installed the recommended driver 352.53 from the NVIDIA website. However, the screen randomly freezes disabling use of keyboard and mouse. I face the same problem on suspend mode. Only way to get it working again is through reboot. The NVIDIA website mentions about possible problems with drivers in certain GTX 9xx configurations (which might be the case). I have tried several clean re-installations using older drivers through the PPA, then separately from NVIDIA website and also the ones bundled with CUDA. So far, the problem remains unresolved. Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Always prefer to use drivers from the official Ubuntu repositories. You can find them in the "Additional Drivers" app, search for it in the Dash. You will need to remove the current drivers and reboot first. After installing the drivers with the Additional Drivers app, reboot and see if everything is fine.

Comment: I removed the current installed drivers and then switched to the suggested driver present in the "Additional Drivers" section, but it doesn't solve the problem. I also tried another manual installation using the .run file from NVIDIA and yet the same issue. I wonder if switching to Ubuntu 12.04 or 15.04 could help?

Comment: Update: I installed Ubuntu 15.04 and everything works fine now.